# load view using ng-inlude

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to load partial view according click on list view options
i have used syncfusion listview control 
also i dont have to change url in address bar...........

```
<div ng-controller="SidebarController">
<a id="treeView" ej-treeview e-fields-datasource="dataList" e-fields-id="id" e-fields-parentid="pid" e-fields-text="name" e-datasource="localdata" e-fields-haschild="hasChild" e-fields-expanded="expanded" e-fields-imageurl="imageUrl" e-nodeselect="selected" />
<div  ng-include="viewurl"/>
```

here is controller code

```
SyncfusionDemoApp.controller('SidebarController', function ($scope, $location, $filter, CommonService) {

//  alert("Sidebarcontroller");

$scope.dataList = ListViewData;

$scope.selected = function (args) {

    for (var i = 0; i < UrlData.length; i += 1) {
        var jsonobject = UrlData[i];
        if (jsonobject.id == args.id) {
            $scope.viewurl = jsonobject.url;
            //$scope.show = true;
            CommonService.Url = UrlData.url;
        }
    }


    alert($scope.viewurl);
    console.log($scope.viewurl);
}



});
```

and here is the JSON:::

```
 var ListViewData = [
             { id: 1, name: "Fiction Book Lists", hasChild: true, expanded: true },
             { id: 2, pid: 1, name: "Fiction Book1", },
             { id: 3, pid: 1, name: "Fiction Book2" },
             { id: 4, name: "Mystery Book Lists", hasChild: true, expanded: true },
             { id: 5, pid: 4, name: "Mystery Book1" },
             { id: 6, pid: 4, name: "Mystery Book2" },
             { id: 7, name: "Horror Novels", hasChild: true },
             { id: 8, pid: 7, name: "Horror Book1" },               
             { id: 9, name: "Novel Lists", hasChild: true },
             { id: 10, pid: 9, name: "Novel Book1" }];


 var UrlData = [{ id: 2, pid: 1, url: '../view/fictionbooks/FictionBook1.html' },
           { id: 3, pid: 1, url: '../view/fictionbooks/FictionBook2.html' },
           { id: 5, pid: 4, url: '../view/mysterybooks/MysteryBook1.html' },
           { id: 6, pid: 4, url: "../view/mysterybooks/MysteryBook2.html" },                                  
           { id: 8, pid: 7, url: "../view/horrorbooks/HorrorBook1.html" },
           { id: 10, pid: 9, url: "../view/novelbooks/NovelBook1.html" }];
```